# LNK2019 unresolved external appears when function is used inside static method

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a C++ Visual Studio 2013 console application which is supposed to make use of a DLL MyDLLlib.dll which I have written. MyDLLlib is written in C. One of the functions is called Get_Version. The prototype is

```
const char *Get_Version();
```

I put this at the top of the source files to make use of the prototype:

```
extern "C"{
#include "MyDLLlib.h"
}
```

If in the function is called in the main as this

```
printf("version %s\n",Get_Version());
```

then it works.

However if I add a class with some static methods and a static method makes a call to Get_Version()

```
const char * ret = Get_Version();
```

then I get a link error:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
"__declspec(dllimport) char * __cdecl Get_Version(void)" (__imp_?Get_Version@@YAPADXZ) 
referenced in function "private: static class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl ServiceDispatch::decoder_Get_Version(class StringBuffer &)" 
(?decoder_Get_Version@ServiceDispatch@@CA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AAVStringBuffer@@@Z)   
D:\devt\CplusPlus\VSTrials\Link_to_MyDLLlib\Link_to_MyDllLib\ServiceDispatch.obj    Link_to_MyDLLlib``
```

I am using the same include.

Any clue as to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Post fragment of `MyDLLlib.h`, in which `Get_Version()` is declared. Probably you messed up `declspec`s and `Get_Version()` has not been exported to DLL.

Comment: #define CLASS_DECLSPEC    __declspec(dllimport) and then CLASS_DECLSPEC char *Get_Version();

Comment: There is no const in my header! But adding it did not solve the problem.

Comment: If the Get_Version had not been exported to the DLL, then why did it work with a simple project when I just called it in the main?

Comment: The project is trying to link to a C++ mangled name: `__imp_?Get_Version@@YAPADXZ`.  There is something you're doing wrong as far as the `extern "C"` goes, but I can't tell what exactly from the snippets you have posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `CLASS_DECLSPEC` defined **always** as `__declspec(dllimport)`, this will not work for sure. Look at this sample:

**DLL_header.h**

```
#if defined( _BUILD_DLL )
#   define DLLAPI           __declspec(dllexport) //Export when building DLL
#else
#   define DLLAPI           __declspec(dllimport) //Import when using in other project
#endif

DLLAPI const char *Get_Version();
```

**DLL_source.cpp**

```
#include "Header.h"

const char *Get_Version()
{
    return "1.1.0.4";
}
```

Build DLL with `_BUILD_DLL` defined.

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "DLL_header.h"

int main()
{
    printf("%s\n", Get_Version());
    return 0;
}
```

Build this, with `_BUILD_DLL` **not defined**.

In your case, it could be problem with `extern "C"` - you include header inside `extern "C"`, which declares `Get_Version()` as having `__cdecl` linkage. But linker is searching for

```
__imp_?Get_Version@@YAPADXZ
```

Which is a mangled (C++) name. Is your DLL a C or C++ project? If your DLL is build as `C` project (not `C++`), put `extern "C"` on `Get_Version()`'s declaration with this `#ifdef`:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

DLLAPI const char *Get_Version();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Either way, remove `extern "C"` from around the `#include`. Also, check if `.lib` file for this DLL is attached to project as dependency.

Comment: In my code CLASS_DECLSPEC is #defined as __declspec(dllexport) in the code that is being used to generate the DLL and as __declspec(import) in the calling code. I used the same trick as yours for DLL_Header.h. Dont forget that I am able to use the DLL function in the context of my calling main.

Comment: I think you meant to write with _BUILD_DLL not defined, in your answer.

Comment: OK, that single modification of placing the extern "C" to inside the header file (and within #ifdef __cplusplus) solved my problem. Thankyou.